# Get total numbers presented in integer with PHP

Tags: php

I don't know how is called the thing I'm looking for, that's why I ask the question.

So, I have numbers like `5, 35, 1823, 355581`. And when I use something like `totalNumbers(35)` then it should return `2`, because it has `3` and `5`. It should be applicable to all the numbers.

I know I can create a code like this:

```
function totalNumbers($int) {
    if($int / 1000 > 0) return 3;
    if($int / 100  > 0) return 2;
    if($int / 10   > 0) return 1;
}
```

But I don't want to add `if` for every number in the world. How do you call this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function

```
$number = 4353;

echo strlen($number);
```

Result: 4

Comment: Oh, I'm so dumb... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
function totalNumbers($int){
  return strlen((string) $int);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a string for that purpose? In the example below we use the function that returns the number of characters in string.

```
function totalNumbers($int) {
    return strlen($int);
}
```